# How to make activity indicator wait for a function

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to use activity indicator to show that my function is loading. It goes so fast that I can see my activity inndicator but the function have not finished loading

Question : **How to use make my activity indicator to false when the functions have really finished to run**

Here my code :

```
  public MainPage()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
            On<iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);

            activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
         
            MyPageName = "home";


            var tasks = new List<Task>();

          
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {

            GetMyLeafLanguage(); //p


            }));


            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {

                    if (App.CheckConnection() == true)
                    {
                        MyAds();  // doit être apres l'initialisation         //
                        LoadtestPage();
                    }
            }));



            Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            #endregion My Initial Tasks

             OnGoTutorial();


            MyNotificationActivate();

            activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;


        }
```

Comment: first, don't do all of this in the constructor

Comment: I need to create a function with all of this  ?

Comment: the page constructor runs **before** the page is even displayed.  `OnAppearing` fires after the UI is ready to display

Comment: what can I do if I want to show the activity of my functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote it, the tasks had to finish their work, **before** the page could display. So the page (finally) displayed, but since the work was already done, the activity indicator immediately disappeared.

These functions should run **after the page is displayed**.

Otherwise, while the tasks run, user will be looking at a blank screen (or at whatever page was showing before you starting creating this page).

---

Unfortunately, there is no cross-platform event that runs after a page displays for the first time.

Here is one way to let the page display while the background work is being done:

```
public partial class MyPage : ...
{
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        BeginWorkWithIndicator();
    }
    
    private void BeginWorkWithIndicator()
    {
        activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

        // The delay gives Xamarin UI a little time, before your background work begins.
        // Without this delay, under some circumstances, the page might not show up as quickly.
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), () => {
            OneTimeBackgroundWork();
            // Run timer only once.
            return false;
        });
    }

    private void OneTimeBackgroundWork()
    {
        ... Long-running work - MUST NOT TOUCH UI ...
        
        // When done.
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            // NOW MAKE UI CHANGES, based on variables set by work above.
            ...
            activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put all my functions please in  OnAppearing? or  OneTimeBackgroundWork ?

Comment: @hko - OneTimeBackgroundWork. The purpose of this code is to do that work on a background thread, so that the page can appear quickly. Until the page appears, the user won't see the activity indicator.