# Navigation to route does not take place

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have created a new application using Xamarin.Forms Shell in Visual Studio 2019. I am trying to get navigation to work and I'm not sure why nothing happens when I call `Shell.Current.GoToAsync`.

Doing the testing with the UWP app that comes with the Shell Tab Bar template, I have the following `app.xaml.cs` in the shared library.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }
```

In the `AppShell` XAML and code-behind I've created a `ShellItem` for my Login route where the app successfully starts out at. I also have a `TabBar` with a route to a `MangaLibraryPage`. I've also registered my routes.

### AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MangaLater.Views"
       Title="MangaLater"
       x:Class="MangaLater.AppShell">

    <ShellItem Route="login" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
    </ShellItem>
        
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="MangaLibraryPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MangaLibraryPage}" />
    </TabBar>


</Shell>
```

### AppShell.cs

```
    public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute("login", typeof(LoginPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MangaLibraryPage), typeof(MangaLibraryPage));
        }
    }
```

The `LoginPage` is pretty simple - it just has a grid with a label and a button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="MangaLater.Views.LoginPage"
                     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MangaLater.Views"
                     Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
                     Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid Padding="0, 60, 0, 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackLayout x:Name="LoginStackLayout"
                         Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Text="Login"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="0, 0, 0, 24"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="36"></Label>
                <Button Text="Sign in with Google" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            BackgroundColor="#4285F4"
                            TextColor="White"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            Margin="16, 8"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I had the view model all wired up and working with navigation but something recently changed that broke it so I've been slowly removing code trying to find what's causing the navigation to not work.

At this point I have no view model and all I've got is code-behind trying to force the navigation to a new Page.

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MangaLibraryPage)}");
        }
    }
```

When the app launches the `OnAppearing` gets called on the `LoginPage` twice. I don't have anyplace in my code above that explicitly calls so I'm not sure why `OnAppearing` is invoked more than once. The `GoToAsync` call gets hit and doesn't throw any exceptions but the navigation never happens. The app stays on the `Loginpage`. Is there something here that stands out as my doing it wrong? The constructor of the `MangaLibraryPay` never gets hit indicating the navigation never instantiates it.

Comment: As a test, make a button that does that GoToAsync. Comment out the line in OnAppearing. Perhaps there is some issue with doing that in a page's OnAppearing. If it works on a button, then we know that the shell navigation is correct.

Comment: Just gave that a shot - added the `OnClick` event handler and the navigation with the same `GoToAsync` call did nothing. The breakpoint is hit and I can step over the code but navigation is essentially a no-op

Comment: Update - I didn't delete the `OnAppearing` override. Once I deleted that method the `OnClick` handler did actually navigate. It appears to be related to the `OnAppearing` override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was broken when I originally ran the minimum example in my original post but it was. I was able to get it working via using an `OnClick` handler. Once I deleted the `OnClick` handler and put the code back into the `OnAppearing` method it worked as well. Not 100% clear on why deleting the `OnAppearing` method, putting it in `OnClick` then deleting `OnClick` and re-overriding the `OnAppearing` fixed it.

Once I had it working I then restored all of my original code and experienced this same behavior again. My original code had a sub-class of `ContentPage` that looked like this:

```
    public abstract class MangaContentPage<TViewModel> : ContentPage where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        protected TViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

        protected IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await BeforeViewModelInitialized();

            this.ServiceProvider = Application.Current.GetServiceProvider();
            this.ViewModel = this.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TViewModel>();

            await this.ViewModel.Initialize();

            this.BindingContext = this.ViewModel;

            await OnViewModelInitialized();
        }

        protected virtual Task BeforeViewModelInitialized()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected virtual Task OnViewModelInitialized()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

The `OnViewModelInitialized` method was then implemented in my child class.

```
public partial class LoginPage : MangaContentPage<LoginPageViewModel>
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override Task BeforeViewModelInitialized()
        {
            var authService = base.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
            UserAuthenticatedResponse authResponse = authService.IsUserAuthenticated();

            if (authResponse.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MangaLibraryPage)}");
            }

            return base.BeforeViewModelInitialized();
        }
    }
```

The navigation stopped working in this approach. I was able to solve for it though by wrapping the call to `OnViewModelInitialized()` using the `Dispatcher` and forcing it to run on the main thread. Watching the suggessted `OnClick` handler from @ToolmakerSteve work fine and the `OnAppearing` work with no upstream async happening made me wonder if this was getting lost in a background thread and never coming back to the main UI thread. Turns out that must have been the case.

My `MangaContentPage<TViewModel>` was modified with `Dispatcher` and that solved this problem.

```
    public abstract class MangaContentPage<TViewModel> : ContentPage where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        protected TViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

        protected IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => this.BeforeViewModelInitialized());

            this.ServiceProvider = Application.Current.GetServiceProvider();
            this.ViewModel = this.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TViewModel>();

            await this.ViewModel.Initialize();

            this.BindingContext = this.ViewModel;

            Dispatcher.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await OnViewModelInitialized());
        }

        protected virtual Task BeforeViewModelInitialized()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected virtual Task OnViewModelInitialized()
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Now that this is working my base class can resolve view models and their dependency via DI, initialize them and give the Page the ability to abort and navigate to a new Page before doing all of the heavy ViewModel work.

Comment: *"if this was getting lost in a background thread"* - right; ALL changes that affect UI should be done on MAIN thread. I don't know why stuff "sometimes" works on a background thread, but I have experienced this myself. I've also experienced other problems running in `OnAppearing`. I think OnAppearing, even though it is on the main thread, is in a state where certain changes get overridden/lost, because of code that Xamarin runs after OnAppearing (in order to actually display the page).

Comment: I didn't mention all that at first, because if that wasn't the issue, I didn't want to send you down a dead-end path. I'm glad I didn't, because the code you wrote to dispatch it is simpler than what I have been using. I start a one-time timer, to get a delay, and on the timer tick invoke on thread. Good to see that BeginInvoke + async/await is sufficient to queue it to a good moment! (TBD whether more complex situation still requires an enforced delay.)

Comment: FYI if do want a delay, `Device.StartTimer` is a good choice. [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673549/199364) I show a pattern I use.