# Xamarin.Forms Reload to observable collection glitches when local DB is involved on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I bind an observable collection to a listview on iOS

```
<flv:FlowListView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Scrolled="listview_allAds_Scrolled"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"       
                    FlowItemAppearing="listview_allAds_FlowItemAppearing"                 
                    Refreshing="listview_allAds_Refreshing"
                    FlowColumnCount="1"
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                    Margin="5,0,5,0"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    x:Name="listview_allAds" />
```

Since newly (I assume since iOS 15 was released), the reload on iOS flickers immensly. For a second you can visibly see the new items being loaded into place where the current items are. After a halfsecond they kind of "move" to the correct position and become scrollable.
This is extermly noticeable.

HOwever, I have found out that the issue is from this lines of code:

The Reloading function: (If I disable this line of code, the flickering is gone)

```
 xR.likeButton1 = ImageSource.FromFile(await GetCorrectFavoriteSymbol(xR.ID1));
```

The simple "has liked, hasnt liked" function:

```
private async Task<string> GetCorrectFavoriteSymbol(string iD)
{
     ReadIfFavType res = await App.DatabaseFAV.GetNoteAsync(Int32.Parse(iD));
    
         if(res != null)
             return "btn_item_favorite.png";
         else
             return "btn_item_nofavorite.png";
}
```

And the DB function that returns a value:

```
public async Task<ReadIfFavType> GetNoteAsync(int adID)
{
    ReadIfFavType yx = null;

    try
    {
        yx = await _databaseFAVs.Table<ReadIfFavType>()
                    .Where(i => i.adID == adID)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return yx;
}
```

So, my assumption is, that it has something to do with the initial "await" inside the reload. But I cannot remove all this because it is required by the local DB:

```
await _databaseFAVs.Table<ReadIfFavType>()
                            .Where(i => i.adID == adID)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

What would be a good way to fix this?

Comment: there are lots of ways you could optimize this - only reload the image if the source changes, for instance.  Or do the db query once to memory, and then query the in-memory copy for each row.

Comment: "newly since iOS 15" - are you saying the same code used to behave more smoothly for you? Adding to Jason's suggestion, it may be best to "pre-load" an image for the first few list items (the ones that are visible at first). And then cache them in memory. I [begin such work in background from OnAppearing, then use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread to get the data to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673549/199364).

Comment: can you guys give me an example please?

Comment: what part of the solution above you dont understand？